# Default Selenium Chrome WebDriver Page load timeout

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, timeout, pageload

Using the Selenium chrome webdriver I am trying to load a page,
But getting the Timeout error for the selenium

like timeout from renderer : 3000

It's the default timeout it is waiting for until the page gets loaded .

I am using groovy selenium to work with chrome.
Everything is fine. Only Timeout error causing issue sometimes.

Does someone have any idea about WHAT IS THE DEFAULT TIMEOUT FOR PAGE LOADING IN CHROME SELENIUM WEBDRIVER ??

And Can I change that timeout ?

If yes how to ?

I am currently using selenium chrome driver v2.9 chrome v.27 in GROOVY.

Answer (score 3):

I have been trying Chrome, Firefox & PhantomJS using Python.
I have been trawling loads of webpages trying to find answers for using a headless web driver WITH a working load page timeout.
There is a lot of confusion between the various answers.
I'll post my findings on this page since it comes up high in a search like 'selenium chrome timeout'.

I can now get chromedriver.exe to work WITH a timeout.
The selenium wrapper seems broken but the following works as per my requirements. Instead of calling:

```
chrome_driver.set_page_load_timeout(my_timeout_secs)
chrome_driver.get( ...... )
```

use:

```
chrome_driver.execute(Command.SET_TIMEOUTS, {
            'ms': float(my_timeout_secs * 1000),
            'type': 'page load'})
chrome_driver.get( ...... )
```

This bypasses the selenium wrapper and sets the timeout with Chrome.
Then just use a standard Selenium catch. The page will timeout, then hit your code after Chrome raises a **TimeoutException** from selenium.common.exceptions

```
try:
    ... set_timeout ...
    ... get url ...

except TimeoutException as e:

    # do whatever you need to here
```

Hope that helps anybody needing headless driver with timeouts.

Thanks,
LJHW

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I finally got the timout working for the Chrome webdriver in python! What it works for me is calling the function `chrome_driver.set_page_load_timout()` before calling `chrome_driver.get()`

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen the [documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits)?

> An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. The default setting is 0.